# How do I get a Roblox Stormtrooper helmet to not be greyed out?

Tags: objects

When I insert an .obj file from Roblox Studio, it greys out the Helmet. Does anyone know how to fix this? [image][image]

Comment: Do you have a material for the helmet? If not, the default is gray.

Comment: I do have a material, it's plastic. Is that default?

Comment: It turns out it was smooth plastic, but it worked for other helmets. I tried to use ice but that didn't work either.

Comment: Check the materials tab on the right for the helmet. Look at the material preview for it. The problem may be the lighting, as the helmet, if glossy metallic, might just be reflecting the world light.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to Blender. Where is the materials tab? Also I inserted the body and the Helmet as 1 object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons why this could be happening.
Listed as follows are some, with their solutions.

1. You are using EEVEE renderer instead of Cycles.

   Change this by going to the Render properties tab, and setting the renderer to *Cycles*.[image][image]
2. You don't have a material set.

   Go to the material tab in the object properties with the object you want a material set for selected, and add/adjust your material.
   [image][image]
3. You need to adjust the material set for your object to something other than the default.

   In the images, I try to achieve a material somewhat like a stormtrooper helmet.
   First adjust the roughness, then adjust the metallic-ness of the *Principled BSDF*.[image][image]
4. I believe you are doing this already, but it is always good to *Compare your object material to another object in the scene, with *Rendered* view selected.

   In these photos I compare the cube object with the helmet material to a blue Suzanne "monkey" head. (Also with a principled shader.)

With no shader adjustment:[image]

With roughness set to 0:[image]

With final material:[image]

One last tip: Adjusting world shader can sometimes give you a better preview of your materials. Here are examples of world brightness and color with a scene of objects with the helmet shader:[image][image][image][image]
Sometimes a dark world background with a bright light helps too:[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: TYSM! Just saw it and I'll try all these different ways! I can finally finish my job.

Comment: I have tried everything you told me to do, but it has not changed. When I changed it to cycles, it just became more blurry. When I changed the material it stayed the same. I changed the roughness and nothing changed. I did all of these together and it doesn't even it was just really dark. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Interesting. Could you give a link to the .blend file? I want to work with it.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Simply upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com, and copy-paste the link provided into your question.

Comment: Ok, I'm nearly done.

Comment: I forgot to press upload after I put everything in was wondering why it wasn't uploading xD. I have done it now and the file should be ForNate.blend because i had no other name. Here it is [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=BJzR8QRq" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/BJzR8QRq/)

Comment: I am not sure why you are not able to change the color of the character. I could. One thing though that I noticed was that the entire character is one mesh, and has different materials assigned to different vertices within itself. You can try going to edit mode and selecting a face on the helmet, then editing the material attached to it. This is all I can really offer to help, alongside with the answer I provided, for I do not see any plain issue with the character's material.

Comment: Could you send me a link with your coloured Stormtrooper, I want to see what you did and also use it maybe to help my one out.